# Redirect a test link to an old one if coming from Google

Tags: .htaccess, seo

So, while doing a project for a client, some trouble with the `.htaccess` lead to a test URL being referenced by Google. Which is not super...

So, I was wondering if it was possible to redirect to the live URL when somebod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ://[^.]+\.google\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/page\.php$ http://domain.com/live/page.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Problem is, we still to access the test one for, well, tests :) It needs to be only when coming from Google :/

Comment: You are testing on Production? :)

Comment: We have two different servers, but we delete the .htpasswd by accident at some point and one page had the time to be indexed... Anyway, seems like it works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have this rule:

```
##  check if it is coming from google
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?google\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^test/?$ /live/ [NC,L,R=301]
```